# Plotting a function with restrictions

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the following $U_a=\frac{wXn_l}{n_a}+H$ as a function of $s$ which is given by the expressions below, where I assign values to the constants

```
Clear["Global`*"]
P=1
w=1;
x=2
nl=2
S=2
sigmaL=0
sigmaH=1
n=6
Sigmai=Subdivide[sigmaL,sigmaH,10]
g=(P*(S-s))/(w*x*nl);
sigma=(-(1-sigmaL*g)-(Sqrt[((1-(sigmaL*g))^2)-(4*g)]/(2*g)));
L=(sigma*P*(S-s))/(w*x*nl);
na=((n-nl)/(1+L));
nf=(L(n-nl))/(1+L);
H=If[s>= 0,H=0,H<= s];
ua=((w*x*nl)/(na))+H;

ua=Simplify[ua];

Plot[ua, sigma>0, {s,0,S}]
```

Though the output message requires more inputs. I'd like to further add the constraint that $nl+na+nf=1$ but I don't know if this should be defined independently or within the plot command.

Comment: `Plot[ua, sigma>0, {s,0,S}]` is non-syntactic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for you.

First let's find where `sigma>0`

```
P=1;w=1;x=2;nl=2;S=2;sigmaL=0;sigmaH=1;n=6;
Sigmai=Subdivide[sigmaL,sigmaH,10];g=(P*(S-s))/(w*x*nl);
sigma=(-(1-sigmaL*g)-(Sqrt[((1-(sigmaL*g))^2)-(4*g)]/(2*g)));
Reduce[sigma>0,s]
```

which returns

```
2<s<2*(2+Sqrt[2])
```

so that tells us what we need to tell `Plot`

```
L=(sigma*P*(S-s))/(w*x*nl);na=((n-nl)/(1+L));
nf=(L(n-nl))/(1+L);H=If[s>= 0,H=0,H<= s];
ua=((w*x*nl)/(na))+H;ua=Simplify[ua];
Plot[ua, {s,2,2*(2+Sqrt[2])}]
```

And that gives you your plot of ua where sigma>0.

If I then look at your additional constraint

```
Reduce[nl+na+nf==1]
```

that returns `False`

So I try

```
Simplify[nl+na+nf-1]
```

to see where that might be zero.  That returns

```
5
```

so it doesn't look like that constraint can be satisfied.

Comment: Oh this is very helpful for sigma. Thank you. For the additional constraint, they should sum to n, not 1, this was my mistake. But I'll try the same approach you suggested.

Comment: Ah, good. And now `Simplify[nl+na+nf==n]` returns `True` so that constraint is always satisfied, at least if I haven't made any mistakes.

Comment: The only thing is that the upper bound for s when sigma>0 is greater than S, and I have defined the maximum value that s takes as S, so I will just change the upper bound.